# Committing only some files in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Many times I'm making two different changes to files in my repository, I want those changes to be treated as two consecutive commits.

For example, in repository

- prog.c
- prog.h
- README.txt

While fixing a bug `prog.c` and `prog.h`, I fixed a typo in `README.txt`. Now I want to commit the change to `prog.c` with its own commit message, and the change to `README.txt` afterwards.

In git, I could easily do that with the index

```
git add prog.c prog.h
git commit -m 'bug #1234'
git commit README.txt -m 'some typos fixed'
```

What's the best way to do that in Mercurial?

**Clarification:** I used (before the edit) a toy example where each changeset spans over a single file. But I want the general answer, what should I do when there are many files in each changeset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mercurial (hg) commit only certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188605/mercurial-hg-commit-only-certain-files)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
hg commit -m "bug #1234" prog.c prog.h
```

then

```
hg commit -m "some typos fixed" README.txt
```

Comment: What if it's more than one file for bug #1234?

Comment: hg commit -m "bug #1234" prog.c prog.h

Comment: If you want all files but README.txt: hg commit -m "bug #1234" -X README.txt

Comment: For a list of all parameters: hg help -v commit

Answer (score 2):

I LOVE the crecord mercurial extension for this purpose: it gives me file by file (and chunk by chunk, and line by line) control over what exactly I want in this commit.

Comment: Or the original record extension which is shipped with mercurial and works on Windows.